# dash-auth not found after installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a program that requires [dash-auth](https://github.com/plotly/dash-auth). I didn't found it when looking into pycharm settings `Available packages`. I tried to install it with conda and pip3. For the latest it was found, but when I try to run again my program it's not found:

```
(homework3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond\richmond2>pip3 install dash-auth
Processing c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\fd\75\a3\8ad3dbd46c1bbac1d63b47a7e4964861b683005ac513082e65\dash_auth-1.3.2-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting plotly
  Downloading plotly-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.1 MB 3.3 MB/s
...
Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 brotli-1.0.7 dash-1.11.0 dash-auth-1.3.2 dash-core-components-1.9.1 dash-html-components-1.0.3 dash-renderer-1.4.0 dash-table-4.6.2 flask-compress-1.5.0 flask-seasurf-0.2.2 itsda
ngerous-1.1.0 plotly-4.6.0 retrying-1.3.3 ua-parser-0.10.0

(homework3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond\richmond2>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from server import app
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond\richmond2\server.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dash_auth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_auth'

(homework3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond\richmond2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `pip3` is not installing `dash-auth` in your conda environment `homework3`. You should use `pip install dash-auth` instead and void using `pip3` in conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda navigator please go to environments->base(root)->Open Terminal.
In the terminal, you can paste "pip install dash-auth" suggested by droptop. This will install dash-auth perfectly. It is working for me.
[image]

[image]